# Проверить на лету есть ли текстовая ссылка в contenteditable

Tags: jquery

Есть html

```
<div contenteditable="true" id="data" type="text">s</div>
```

В него вводится текст. Как на лету проверить есть ли в веденном тексте текстовая ссылка, например http://example.ru если такая ссылка есть вывести alert если нет то ни делать ничего.

**UPD**
Но не брать в учет если ссылка уже заключена в тег `a`

Answer (score 0):

> Но не брать в учет если ссылка уже заключена в тег a

Алгоритм следующий: вначале из строки удаляем все теги `<a ....>...</a>`, а потом в оставшейся строки ищем ссылки.

Под ссылками я понимаю строки, содержащие подстроку `http://` или `https://`

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  function removeA(str) {
//    return str.replace(/<a\s.*?<\/a>/g, "");
    return str.replace(/&lt;a\s.*?&lt;\/a&gt;/g, "");
  }
  
  function isLink(str) {
    return removeA(str).search(/https?:\/\//) !== -1;
  }
  
  $('body').on('input','[contenteditable]', function() {
    if (isLink(this.innerHTML)) {
      console.log("Link");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true" id="data" type="text">s</div>
```

Comment: Срабатывает если находит просто http:// а нужно чтобы находил именно ссылку, например http:// sddsfdsfsdf.com

Comment: @Tokwiro дайте определение ссылки

Comment: Ссылки могут быть разные, нет определенных ссылок. Есть контейнер contenteditable в нем вот для примера такой текст "  супер текст <a href="">http://example.ru</a> вторая ссылка http://test.ru " - здесь в учет поиска ссылку которая заключена в тег a брать не нужно, только ту которая без тега a.

Comment: @Tokwiro Если неизвестно что искать, то задача не решается. `site.com`, `http://site.com`, `ftp://site.com`, `mailto:name@site.com`, `tel:+xxxxxx`. Что из этого для вас является ссылками?

Comment: только http://site.com , https//site.com все остальное нет.

Comment: @Tokwiro О как! А что из этого является ссылками `information.aero`, `кто.рф`, `ушел.спать`?

Comment: http:// example. зона

Comment: @Tokwiro Вы противоречите сами себе. До этого наличие `http://` было необязательным

Comment: Я писал с http это местный редактор его скрил наличие http или https обязательно, также обязательная зона .ru .org .com и другие.

Comment: `и другие`. Какие другие? `http://information.aero`, `http://кто.рф` вполне себе реальные сайты. А если такая ссылка `http://google.com.ua` или такая `https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/.aero`? Разговор ни о чем. Дайте однозначное определение ссылки. Без слов `и другие`, `например`, `разные`

Comment: Вот три конкретных примера http:// google.com , http:// example.org , https:// site.com.ua